# Codeigniter to PDF

Tags: codeigniter, pdf-generation

I am doing my Project in CodeIgniter framework

I am converting php file to PDF. I am showing my content in fancy box in that if i click PDF it generating PDF, in this no issues.

My issue is in fancy box i can see English, Numeric and Arabic letters as it is.

But, when it comes to PDF Arabic letters alone changed to Question mark like this ?????.

To get Arabic letters in PDF what i have to do. I think UTF-8 some but I am not clear.

Can any ONE Help.

Comment: Are your php files encoded in utf-8?

Comment: Hi i am new to this i don't know what you asking php files encoded. I think you syaing  $dompdf->load_html($html, 'UTF-8'); I am i right?

Comment: I did lik this also                                                                                          $html = utf8_decode($html);                                        $dompdf->load_html($html);

Comment: In your source code editor, you must have some encoding setting. It's usually ANSI.

Comment: if not, try $html = utf8_encode($html);

Comment: ya i already tried $html = utf8_encode($html);                                              is not working.

Comment: What about the php file encoding?

Comment: yes i encode using this code                                                                        $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

Comment: my dompdf_helper.php Arabic letters are showing as ???? in my pdf                           function pdf_create($html, $filename, $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $date=date("m_d_Y");
    $filename = $filename.'_'.$date.'_'.rand();
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');   
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    //$dompdf->set_paper($_POST["paper"], $_POST["orientation"]);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("$filename".".pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working

In php page put below code in head. The issue was in my css font so only i got Arabic letters as ????? in pdf

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8"/>
```

In css

```
th
            {
                font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
                /*font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;*/ This is wrong
                border: solid 1px black;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
```